# Radius of convergence of power series, with a recursive sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having some troubles with the following problem:

Let $a_0,a_1,a_2\in \mathbb{C}$ , we define $$a_{n+3} = a_{n+2} + a_{n+1} − a_n, \ \ n \in \mathbb{N}_0 $$

I need to find the radius of convergence of  $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nz^n$$

here is what I have:

From the definition of $(a_n)$ we can see:
$$a_{n+3} -a_{n+2}= a_{n+1}  − a_n, \ \ n \in \mathbb{N}_0 $$

so if $n$ is even  and $n\geq2$ we have that:
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=a_1-a_0$$

if $n$ is odd  and $n\geq2$ we have that:
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=a_2-a_1$$

I define $c_1=a_1-a_0$  and $c_2 = a_2-a_1$

so we know that:
$$a_n=a_2+c_1+c_2+c_1+c_2...+c_i$$

where $i=1$ if $n$ is odd and $i=2$ if $n$ is even.

I'm stuck here, some hint or idea will great :). Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Comment: You can solve the recurrence more easily by noting that $a_{n+3} - a_{n+1} = a_{n+2} - a_n$. The result is that the odd- and even-numbered coefficients form arithmetic sequences with the same step. From there use the lim sup criterion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_{n+3} - a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} + a_n = 0 \rightarrow x^3 - x^2 - x + 1 = 0 \rightarrow (x+1)(x-1)^2 = 0$. Thus: $a_n = A(-1)^n + B + Cn$. Can you solve for $A, B, C$?

Comment: this takes all the fun xD, thanks